# how include multiple jquery version for multi jquery plugins to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

first of all I see this question and use noConflict:

[Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

But what I want is to load 2 jquery plugins (superfish.js and jstree) and each use different version of jquery (in their core library I mean), How can I do this?

edit: I put what I done so far and what I want:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>                
// i do not use noConflict for support other plugins 

<!-- load jQuery 1.3.2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.9.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_9 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Now for example I want to load superfish.js to use jquery_1_9:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/superfish.js">   </script>
```

superfish.js use `$` and it refer to jquery version 1.7

Comment: can you please add which two versions you want to use ?

Comment: I want to use 1.7 and 1.9

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Comment: @jQuery I just edit my question ;)

Comment: did you check link which i provide ??? you can replace $ to jQuery_1_9 in you plugin?

Comment: @jQuery  I use it for jstree plugin and it give me error in firebug: TypeError: a.expr.createPseudo is not a function
 

...f&&f!==b?f:this):!1},a.expr[":"].jstree=a.expr.createPseudo

Answer (score 0):

If js file 'superfish.js' loading from local assets then by providing wrapper to init (main function or entry point of function) function of this file we can solve it.

```
<script>
var jQuery_1_9 = $.noConflict(true);
initailizeFun(jQuery_1_9); // inside function of superfish.js which initiates plugin.
</script>
```

But problem here is if are using another version of jquery like 'jQuery_1_8' then setting user data to this 'jQuery_1_8' will not be accessible in superfish.js.